# Life Cycle of a Spring Bean

Tags: spring

I came to know that IOC container is responsible for the creation of bean, injection of dependency and lifecycle management. Then, what is the internal implementation of IOC container? What is the process happens after the bean is created and before its destruction?

Comment: Your question is too general. Check this out: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Answer (score 12):

1. Spring instantiates the bean.
2. Spring injects values and bean references into the bean’s properties.
3. If the bean implements `BeanNameAware`, Spring passes the bean’s ID to the `setBeanName()` method.
4. If the bean implements `BeanFactoryAware`, Spring calls the `setBeanFactory()` method, passing in the bean factory itself.
5. If the bean implements `ApplicationContextAware`, Spring calls the `setApplicationContext()` method, passing in a reference to the enclosing application context.
6. If the bean implements the `BeanPostProcessor` interface, Spring calls its `postProcessBeforeInitialization()` method.
7. If the bean implements the `InitializingBean` interface, Spring calls its `afterPropertiesSet()` method. Similarly, if the bean was declared with an `init-method`, then the specified initialization method is called.
8. If the bean implements `BeanPostProcessor`, Spring calls its `postProcessAfterInitialization()` method.
9. At this point, the bean is ready to be used by the application and remains in the application context until the application context is destroyed.
10. If the bean implements the `DisposableBean` interface, Spring calls its `destroy()` method. Likewise, if the bean was declared with a `destroy-method`, the specified method is called.

[image]

Comment: Where does the BeanFactoryPostProcessor fit into this order?

Comment: This answer is from [Chapter 1. Springing into action - Spring in Action, 4th Edition: Covers Spring 4](https://livebook.manning.com/book/spring-in-action-fourth-edition/chapter-1/144)